# Can we override Tuple2 equals methods in Spark?

Tags: java, scala

I am from Java baackground and learning Spark using Java. I would like to know if we can override Tuple2 key comparison logic for further key related operations on Tuple2 (the same way we can do with hashMap by overriding equals and hashCode methods in Java).

(I checked https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html but I could not find anything related)

Comment: Tuple2 is a third-party class in the standard library, just like you cannot override the `equals` method on a `String`, you cannot do it for `Tuple2` either. You provided an example of overriding equals/hashCode for a hash map; but you do these overrides on *your own* types for them to be usable with `HashMap`. This seems to be an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); it would be a good idea to explain what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I have a list of CustomObjects and I would like to match them on a probabilistic algorithm (e.g. few params matches) and would like to consider them same. Using Tuple2, I would further perform various operations on the key (e.g. aggregation)